# Electron ignores @css prefers-color-scheme

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, electron

I have made an Electron project and now added dark mode support to it.
The problem is that it for some reason doesn't work.

Below is my `dark.css` styling included in every page

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
body, .full-screen, #code {
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  background: #444 !important;
  color: #e4e4e4 !important;
}
.title-bar {
  background: rgb(58, 58, 58) !important;
}
}
```

How is this possible? 
I've heard you can use `systemPreferences.isDarkMode()` but that is for the main process and I want it to be reflected in the frontend + I want it to update automatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had to reinstall NPM and electron. I also had to run `npm config set ignore-scripts false`. That was the trick